# Can't able to open any folder in the Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: directory

I cant able to open any folder. All the files in the desktop is vanished. Right click on the desktop is also not working. If I give specific file name, its opening. But folder not opening. All happening from yesterday only. I forcefully shutdown the system. After this all these mess up..
What to do.. I'm certainly new to ubuntu.

Comment: Do the icons reappear if you (re-)start Nautilus (press Alt+F2, type `nautilus`, and press Enter)?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. What have you tried so far? Please help us help you by reviewing http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

check permission of directory using

```
ls -l
```

and change the permission using chmod.

for more on permissions with chmod issue the command `man chmod`

Comment: Hi Chirag. Thanks for the reply. What to do with the chmod. I typed chmod in the terminal. Its showing missing operand. When I plugged the pendrive, a text box with "unable to open the folder. No application is registered as handling this file" is appeared. Please help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DavidFoerster This is an attempt to answer the question.